# Can I write e(mathematical constant) in fraction?

Tags: solution-verification, natural-numbers, geometric-progressions, constants

[Proof of e can be in fraction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CjTcD.png)

e is 2.718281828.....
so as you can see, there is a pattern. So, I break it down into 2.7 + 0.01828 + 0.0000001828 .....

and then I use sum of infinity to get the fraction

Well, in mathematics theory , e cannot be in fraction. But I tried to use sum of infinity and proof it that it can be in fraction. Am I correct?

Comment: $e$ is transcendental. You are incorrect in believing that the decimal expansion continues to repeat after the 9th decimal. It does not.

Comment: $e=2.71828182845904...$

Comment: Look a bit further in the decimal expansion of $e$: $$e=2.718281828\color{red}{4590}...$$ It's messier than one might expect at first, and - being irrational (indeed, transcendental) - does not eventually become repetitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have proved that

$$
e' = 2.718281828(1828)...
$$

is rational. This is a special case of a more general statement that a number is rational if and only if its decimal expansion is [repeating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeating_decimal) or terminating. However, $e'$ is not the same number as

$$
e = \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n = 2.718281828\color{red}{45904}... .
$$

In fact, it is a fairly well-known fact that [$e$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)) is irrational (transcendental even). See for example [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_that_e_is_irrational) for a few proofs of this fact.

That said, your observation provides a convenient mnemonic for the first ten digits of $e$!

Answer (score 0):

[$e$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)) can be represented in a [continued fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction). See the [List of representations of $e$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_representations_of_e).

$e=2+\cfrac{1}{1+\cfrac{1}{2+\cfrac{1}{1+\cfrac{1}{1+\cfrac{1}{4+\cfrac{1}{1+\cfrac{1}{1+\ddots\,}}}}}}}=1+\cfrac{2}{1+\cfrac{1}{6+\cfrac{1}{10+\cfrac{1}{14+\cfrac{1}{18+\cfrac{1}{22+\cfrac{1}{26+\ddots\,}}}}}}}$

$e=2+\cfrac{1}{1+\cfrac{1}{2+\cfrac{2}{3+\cfrac{3}{4+\cfrac{4}{5+\ddots}}}}}= 2+\cfrac{2}{2+\cfrac{3}{3+\cfrac{4}{4+\cfrac{5}{5+\cfrac{6}{6+\ddots\,}}}}}$

$e=2+\cfrac{1}{1+\cfrac{2}{5+\cfrac{1}{10+\cfrac{1}{14+\cfrac{1}{18+\ddots\,}}}}} =1+\cfrac{2}{1+\cfrac{1}{6+\cfrac{1}{10+\cfrac{1}{14+\cfrac{1}{18+\ddots\,}}}}}$